# Phalcon 3.04 IndexController handler class cannot be loaded

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I made a project with modules type with this command

```
phalcon project simkontrolprogja --type=modules
```

When i am adding new module in my project called administrator by use this command

```
phalcon module administrator
```

i have add the module on config/loader.php
[image: in config/loader.php]

```
$loader->registerClasses([
    'Simkontrolprogja\Modules\Frontend\Module' => APP_PATH . '/modules/frontend/Module.php',
    'Simkontrolprogja\Modules\Administrator\Module' => APP_PATH . '/modules/administrator/Module.php',
    'Simkontrolprogja\Modules\Cli\Module'      => APP_PATH . '/modules/cli/Module.php'
]);
```

On bootsrap_web.php

[image]

```
$application->registerModules([
        'frontend' => ['className' => 'Simkontrolprogja\Modules\Frontend\Module'],
        'admin' => ['className' => 'Simkontrolprogja\Modules\Administrator\Module'],
    ]);
```

On Module.php

[image]

```
/**
     * Registers an autoloader related to the module
     *
     * @param DiInterface $di
     */
    public function registerAutoloaders(DiInterface $di = null)
    {
        $loader = new Loader();

        $loader->registerNamespaces([
            'Simkontrolprogja\Administrator\Controllers' => __DIR__ . '/controllers/',
            'Simkontrolprogja\Administrator\Models'      => __DIR__ . '/models/'
        ]);

        $loader->register();
    }
```

and when i try to access the module, this is happen
[image]

IndexController.php

[image]

```
namespace Simkontrolprogja\Modules\Administrator\Controllers;
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

}
```

Hope some body help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please post your code, not images

Comment: Where is the IndexController?

Comment: namespace Simkontrolprogja\Modules\Administrator\Controllers;

class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a case sensitive file system?

Try capitalising the path to your namespace.